# Yii2 Category_has_Product table

Tags: sql, yii2, key

I have a table `Category_has_Product`. It contains the two columns: `categoryId` and `productId`. How can I get products from specific category ordered by name?

Comment: don't you need a table with `productId` and `productName` for that?

Comment: I have this table too.

Comment: Are you looking for a Yii2 select query as in [here](http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/select-query-sql-queries/)?  Are you having a problem with the SQL itself or with the Query class?  This looks like a straightforward inner join to me.

Comment: I want make this:
SELECT *
FROM Product
INNER JOIN Category_has_Product
ON Product.id=Category_has_Product.productId
WHERE CategoryId = 1;
but using models from Yii2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by adding the following method inside your Category model:

```
public function getProducts() {
    return $this->hasMany(Product::className(), ['id' => 'productId'])
        ->viaTable('Category_has_Product',['categoryId' => 'id'])
        ->orderBy('productName ASC');
}
```

Just make sure the field names are correct. The first 'id' has to be the one from your Product table, and the second 'id' has to be from your Category table.